# Is integral curve a embedded 1 dimensional submanifold of the given manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry

I can easily see a proof that shows its going to be an immersed submanifold . (I am removing the case if the vector field at that point is 0). I am not able to see if it's a embedded submanifold or not? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In general, no, absolutely not! Consider $M = \Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z^2$ and $X= \partial/\partial x + a\partial/\partial y$, where $a$ is irrational. Then an integral curve of this is a line with irrational slope, which is *dense* in $M$. About as far from embedded you can get! You should expect that the "generic" vector field has non-embedded integral curves.

Comment: Will you please elaborate the last statement sir ?

Comment: @Illuminata: It's not a rigorous statement, though it could be made to be. I just mean that if I hand you a "random" vector field, you should expect that it has non-embedded integral curves. It's rare for all your integral curves to be embedded.

Comment: Okk ...I understood. ..thanks a lot.